# Qual a melhor forma de mapear entidade com chave composta JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

Tenho duas tabelas para mapear em duas entidades.
Preciso listar na tela dessa forma:

```
Id | Produto | Cliente | Razão Social  | País   | Estado
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | TV      | 000001  | Jao da Silva  | Brasil | São Paulo
2  | PC      | 000001  | Jao da Silva  | Brasil | Rio de Janeiro
3  | TV      | 000002  | Maria Pereira | EUA    | Florida
```

Sendo que o país e estado é um controle de região de reserva de produtos, não é a localização do cliente.
A segunda tabela é genérica com chave composta... Até aí tudo certo.
Basta mapear utilizando `InheritanceType` e criar a `IdClass`.
O problema é que não tenho o campo TIPO (`DiscriminatorColumn`) na tabela de RESERVAS
O sistema ERP é antigo, não tenho como modificar as tabelas. Já tentei fazer a query sem mapear com DTO fazendo join left, já tentei subquery. Mas não consegui.

Qual a melhor forma de resolver?

Reservas:

```
|ID| PRODUTO|CLIENTE|PAIS|ESTADO|
---------------------------------
|1 | 1      |000001 |001 |SP    |
|2 | 2      |000001 |001 |RJ    |
|3 | 1      |000002 |002 |FL    |
```

Elementos:

```
|TIPO|ID |DESCRICAO     |
--------------------
|NAZ |001|Brasil        |
|NAZ |002|EUA           |
|EST |SP |São Paulo     |
|EST |RJ |Rio de Janeiro|
|EST |FL |Florida       |
```

Entidade 1:

```
@Entity 
public class Reserva implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PRODUTO")
    private String produto;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cliente cliente;

    @Column(name = "PAIS")
    private String pais;

    @Column(name = "ESTADO")
    private String estado;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Entidade 2:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TIPO")
@IdClass(ElementoPK.class)
public abstract class Elemento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TIPO")
    private String tipo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO")
    private String descricao;

    //Getters & Setters
}

public class ElementoPK implements Serializable {

    private String tipo;
    private String id;

    //Getters & Setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("NAZ")
public class Pais extends Elemento implements Serializable {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EST")
public class Estado extends Elemento implements Serializable {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A melhor forma de mapear uma entidade com chave composta utilizando o JPA (Java Persistence API) é criar uma classe de entidade separada para representar a chave composta e anotá-la com a anotação @Embeddable. Em seguida, na classe de entidade principal, você deve declarar um atributo do tipo da classe de chave composta e anotá-lo com a anotação @EmbeddedId.
Por exemplo, suponha que você tenha uma entidade chamada Person que tem uma chave composta formada pelos atributos firstName e lastName. A classe de chave composta seria definida da seguinte maneira:

@Embeddable
public class PersonId implements Serializable {

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

// getters and setters
```

}

A classe de entidade principal, Person, seria definida da seguinte maneira:

@Entity
public class Person {

```
@EmbeddedId
private PersonId id;

// outros atributos e métodos
```

}

Essa é a forma recomendada de mapear uma entidade com chave composta utilizando o JPA. Isso permite que você crie uma classe de chave composta separada que pode ser reutilizada em outras entidades e facilita a manutenção do código.